# Stack up and inner layers of shield structure used in RF PCBs

Tags: rf, grounding

In such RF PCBs, it can be easily seen that the chassis ground passes through the middle of the PCB. My question is, is the chassis ground directly connected with the signal ground in such RF PCBs? I know it is not correct to generalize, but can you suggest any reference design? Other issues are that this kind of chassis ground passing through the middle point of the PCB passes only through the upper and lower layers? What kind of structure do the inner layers contain? Blind vias or...?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The chasis ground don't passes through the middle of the pcb. This technique is a multipoint grounding, the opposite of masses connected at a single point (a technique to be banned in EMC test because valable only below ~100kHz). In general the chassis ground is always directly connected with the signal ground for several reasons ; shielding, common mode current evacuate, equipotentiality, ...

Comment: ''(a technique to be banned in EMC test because valable only below ~100kHz)'' so are you saying here that the multipoint grouding structure is only applicable at 100khz  below due to emc concerns?

Comment: Could you add a source for your images?

Comment: @electronx, Let me quote "Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering, Henry W. Ott" page 127, figure 3-18 ; "At high frequency, single-point grounds become multipoint grounds because of stray capacitance." And page 128, figure 3-19 ; "Multipoint ground system is a good choice at frequencies above about 100 kHz".

Answer (score 1):

The stackup is most likely ground all layers, except for what few traces need pass through the boundary -- stripline RF traces, power, and logic and control signals.

A DC circuit / galvanic safety ground concept is simply inadequate to approach RF design with.  Clear that from your mind and start over.  What does a circuit element think as "ground"? The metal beside it.  Wrap a circuit around with metal, and that becomes -- if not circuit ground (to be clear, "ground" is still a matter of definition), then at least an effective shield through which no EM waves can pass (given adequate thickness of course), and by consequence, a damn good reference plane to choose as circuit ground.

This is what is important about grounding at RF.

We can build circuits in isolated sections, enclosed in their own metal shells, and using that shell as circuit common ("ground"), and referencing all signals (in and out of the local circuit) to it.

There is no ground loop, because there is no voltage drop across the massive metal shell.  (Actually, there is, depending on where "across" shall be measured at; things are always more interesting than simple quips.  But for circuit purposes, this is effectively truth.)

(Also, DC resistance of the ground structure still exists, where "DC" is relative to the resistance and self-inductance of the material -- which is to say, frequencies where skin depth is comparable to or larger than material thickness.  But notice, quite massive metal parts are used here: multilayer boards with via stitching; solid aluminum shields with milled pockets.  We would be operating a quite sensitive (at DC) circuit to worry about DC voltage drop across such a structure!)